# how to remove spacing in table when i am converting html to pdf

Tags: html, pdf

remove spacing to table when i convert it html to PDF its take space and its taking space only in PDF not in html 
 remove spacing to table when i convert it html to PDF its take space and its taking space only in PDF not in html

URL :- [http://designmyplanner.com/dev/planners/testpdf]

print screen :- [http://prntscr.com/f1rg13]

Answer (score 1):

If You are using `HTML AGILITY PACK` or another `Method` to parse your HTML before converting.
Use :

> string=System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(string,pattern,
>   replacement);

or

> string = string.Trim();